# Difference between "no" and "nope"

Tags: word-usage

When is it correct to use *no* and *nope*? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: [General reference](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006042608761)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, considering J.R.'s answer, I don't think one would be able to learn that "nope" cannot always be used in the place of "no".  Especially if English isn't the person's first language.

Comment: @Bidella: We all have our own concept of what constitutes "General reference", and what role ELU should play in the teaching of English to non-native speakers. I'm not suggesting there's anything incorrect in J.R.'s answer, or that it's not useful to Juanillo. But the first sentence in the FAQ says ELU *is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.* I just don't think this question meets that criterion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yep, that makes sense. I understand now.

Comment: @Bidella: In retrospect, considering John's reply, I think I was (partly) wrong. If OP had asked *why* the informal "*Yep*" and "*Nope*" and with a **P** it would have been a perfectly good question!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yahoo! answers is not general reference. It's too unreliable. (The Yahoo! answers link didn't cite any dictionaries, so it wasn't pointing to a general reference)

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: The question has been validly asked on [learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30/). Even John Lawler can't find anything useful to say about it here apart from talking about the pronunciation. Native speakers don't need to look up things like this - it's *not* a suitable question to have here, irrespective of what you think of that Yahoo link.

Comment: [General reference](http://www.wordnik.com/words/nope).  Clearly outlines that it is informal, and that it only fills the adverbial form of 'no', not the other variants.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any difference?  Nope - not in meaning anyway.

Actually, "nope" means "no," but only in the sense of the opposite of "yes."  Therefore, you might use it to answer a yes-or-no question in the negative, but you would **never** say, "*We found nope errors during the inspection*," or "*There was nope way Dave would ever surrender*."

That said, "nope" is informal, and should only be used in writing in the most informal of contexts.

Comment: Shouldn't "We found no errors" actually be "We didn't find any errors" or "We found that there were no errors"?

Comment: "We found no errors" and "We didn't find any errors" both say essentially the same thing.  I prefer the former, which is more direct.

Comment: Can you find something that isn't there?

Comment: In context, yes.  Assuming the inspection was aimed at finding errors, "We found no errors" summarizes the result of the inspection.

Comment: Reminds me the *Hitchiker's  Guide To The Galaxy* game, where for most of the game your inventory of items contains *no tea*.

Comment: Also, informally, a verb. "I noped right out of there as soon as I heard the skittering noises in the dark corners"

Answer (score 10):

J.R. is correct to note that *nope* occurs only as a one-word answer to Y/N questions, and not for other uses of *no*.

The final "pe" in *nope* comes from the way it is pronounced, ending with **firmly** closed lips to signal the end of the word, answer, utterance, and discussion.

The "p" part is produced by closing the lips, and the silent "e" comes from the English spelling system, which requires it there to keep the pronunciation of "o" as tense /o/ even though it's followed by (what sounds like) a consonant.

Similar reasons account for *yup* as a variant of *ya ~ yeah*, which needs no final "e" because the vowel is not tense.