# Why do we write "Tsk" for the sound of disapproval?

Tags: orthography

Wikipedia says [alveolar clicks are found only in Africa/Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_clicks), which isn't true at all.

For instance, there's the one usually done twice in rapid succession with the tongue against the upper side teeth/gums - to "gee up" a horse, indicate "mock-conspiratorial" agreement, etc.

So far as I know, we don't even *attempt* an onomatopoeic written representation of that one, but the one formed by suction against the back of the front teeth/palate is normally written as either "tut" or "tsk". Sometimes people actually **say** "tut" or "tut-tut" (presumably, influenced by the written form).

But I've never heard anybody say anything remotely resembling "tsk". So where does the "k" come from in that written representation?

Comment: Well, if they wanted to write it in the first place, they had to write **something,** didn't they? And exclamation point was already taken. "Tsk" has the advantage that it's unpronounceable and not confusable with any other word. Plus it starts with the same consonant as "tut", which is a vocalized version that also occurs, in print and in speech (though it sounds awfully dated now).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree that clicks are common.  I find that the one to express disapproval is at the front of the mouth, and the one to get the horse to go is made with the side of the tongue against the side of the roof of the mouth.  It seems to me that both are made with an entirely different air flow than the letter "T".

Comment: @John Lawler: I think you've probably got it there! It's *unpronounceable and not confusable with any other word*.

Comment: @Julia: I don't know if it counts as a "click" or not, because the air goes out rather than in, but there's the "unvoiced T" which is usually a dismissive "I don't care" (similar to "unvoiced P", which I invariably associate with Mediterranean types).

Comment: [t] and [p] are all ready unvoiced. Do you mean **unreleased** (like the [p] in [_nope_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59652/difference-between-no-and-nope/59670#59670))?

Comment: @John Lawler: No, I mean when the larynx isn't doing anything, but a small amount of air (powered from the lungs) is released with the tongue or lips in the T or P position. I don't know technical names for any of these things, nor do I know if there even *are* "popular" names for the "utterances" themselves, but I think they do have relatively standard "meanings".

Comment: In dutch we say either tss or tsss (number of s-es can vary) or tut tut. So it is not only in English

Comment: @Michel Keijzers: Ah! "Tsss" would make more sense to me! I take it you still apply this to the same "suction click" I'm talking about here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes same sound but maybe longer than Tsk (that's probably a short s, tssss can be quite long, slowly fading out)

Comment: @Michel Keijzers: I don't understand. The noise I'm talking about *can't* be "drawn out". It's formed by the suction of drawing the tongue down from the front top of the palate/back of the top front teeth, allowing a short sudden inrush of air, and causing a "click". It's physically impossible to stretch it out.

Comment: I've heard people say "tisk, tisk" an "tut tut" about as often as the...um...alveolar/dental click.

Comment: @FF - that's probably an ejective stop, then.

Comment: The other alternative to *tsk* and *tut* that I see is *tch*.

Comment: No duplicate. I am asking about the ortographic origin,

Comment: In what way does the following post answer my question???

Comment: Why do you think it is a duplicate?

Comment: I think my question is clear...it askis about its orthographic origin and early usage.

Comment: @JOSH: I asked *where does the "k" come from in that written representation?* I think almost any question of the general form *Where does X come from?* covers things like *origin / early usage* (and I'm clearly asking about the *orthography*, since I don't accept that "reverse-eye-dialect / backformed" pronunciations have any significant currency).

Comment: Yes, but I am asking about something different, I think it originated in cartoons and I am asking for a possible confirmation. The answer posted here don't say nothing about its original usage and when and where the expression was first used. They just make phonological assumptions that may have influenced  orthography, something I am not really concerned about!!!

Comment: The ***Full*** OED has this for their 1947 "first citation": *L. Pike Phonemics ii. 41/1   Do you get..a sound resembling the noise of commiseration which is **sometimes written in literature** as ‘tsk-tsk’, or ‘tut-tut’*. Fairly obviously the implication is that it was well-established by then. Personally, I doubt the writer would have been particularly thinking of *cartoons* as "literature", and I don't understand why you might think this could be a credible "etymology". But if that's what you think, why not post it as an answer here, rather than asking if others agree *as a new question?*

Comment: Your last comment could actually be the basis for a good answer to my question. The reason I think that tsk may have originated in cartoons is that  tsk, unlike other onomatopoeic terms, is relatively recent and cartoons have always abundantly used such terms. I don't think this assumption can be used to make an answer to your question.

Comment: @JOSH: I still don't really understand why you think cartoons should be especially relevant to onomatopoeic orthography in this case. I know outfits like DC Comics (which got started in the 1930s) later published all sorts of "superhero" stuff littered with *Kapow! Blam! Skreeech!* But here's [tsk tsk](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22latter+saying+tsk+tsk%22) in 1882, which way predates Amerioca's golden age of action comics. [This](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/05/the-language-of-comics/) might interest you though.

Comment: I don't  not really understand why you insist I shouldn't ask my question, I will reopen it soon btw. The 1882 snippet is not certain though, there is a 2016 edition shown on the same page.

Comment: I'm not stopping you asking another question. I just commented [Can you explain why this question isn't a duplicate of that earlier one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362736/is-the-term-tsk-derived-from-cartoons#comment844269_362736). I have to say you haven't convinced *me*, and arguably if these current comments belong anywhere they belong on your currently-deleted question, since they may be relevant to anyone considering voting on it. I don't know what "a 2016 edition shown on the same page" means, but there's no doubt Ellen Charlotte Hope-Edwardes wrote *Eau-de-Nil* in 1882.

Comment: You are referring to the [dental click](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_click), rather than the alveolar click.

Comment: @pacoverflow: I said *the back of the front teeth / **palate*** in my question text. I see Wikipedia say the ***dental click*** is [more properly called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_click#:~:text=Dental%20(or%20more%20precisely%20denti,tsk!) ***denti-alveola*** anyway, but I can assure you that at least when ***I*** make the sound I'm talking about, the tip of my tongue is nowhere near my teeth- it's pressed well back on the roof of my palette. Basically, the same as /t/ except with reversed airflow direction, and /t/ is the archetypal "alveolar consonant" (unlike /ð/ and /θ/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably for the same reason that dogs barking don't say "woof".  "Tsk" is a phonetic sound that corresponds roughly to the tutting sound.  I note that my tongue and teeth end up in roughly the same part of my mouth when I say "tsk" as when I tut, whereas saying "tut" gives a totally different mouth shape.

Comment: This answer reminds me of the joke where the dog says, "Was I supposed to say DiMaggio?"

Comment: haha - dogs don't say "woof" because they can't read! Whereas people sometimes say "tut" simply because they *can* read!

Comment: My dog does woof - and my daughter's first "word" was woof since that's what she heard said by the dog.  But her second word was "mootz" for milk, so maybe I shouldn't read too much into it.

Answer (score -1):

*Tsk, tsk*!  Although I haven't been keeping score, I believe I've heard *tsk* uttered at least as often as I've heard *tut*.  Maybe that's an American thing?

Side note: An [Ngram analysis](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tsk%20tsk,tut%20tut&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=4) shows that, at least in writing, the two terms are running pretty much neck-at-neck at this juncture.  (I opted to compare "tsk, tsk" with "tut, tut" - using a single utterance of each word includes many references to King Tutankhamun, thereby skewing the results).

Comment: I'm surprised. You really hear people saying "Tsk" in earnest? I think that *must* be an American thing. I suppose in more than half a lifetime I must have heard it said facetiously a few times, but in my experience when people actually mean it, it's nearly always the alveolar click itself, or very occasionally "tut".

Comment: I believe that the 'k' in 'tsk' is a stop, but I really do hear 'ts'.

Comment: @FumbleFIngers: Yes, no joke.  Moreover, out of curiosity, I asked my wife, and she said the same thing - she's more likely to hear _tsk_ than _tut_.  (She even said, "Tut... that must be a British thing.")