# Name for that sound you make with pursed lips

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

I tried searching, but couldn't find anything. What's that sound called, the one you make when you purse your lips and make that kissing kind of sound? I guess people make the sound in different contexts, but for example:

Person 1 does all sorts of complicated things to accomplish a task, Person 2 does it easily. Upon seeing Person 2's method, Person 1 may make this sound.

If there are any Kannadigas, in Kannada it's called *lochhguttodu*.

Comment: I am from a neighbouring state (TN) and still I have no clue what that is. Perhaps you should provide an mp3 clipping making the sound yourself.

Comment: Seems like "lip trill" would be the most appropriate term the way you presented it.

Comment: @asymptotically. Rather than leave it to guessing maybe better to upload a short Vimeo or such video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you thinking of *[tsking](http://www.yourdictionary.com/tsking)*?  I realize that the action isn't the same, but I'm not sure there is a separate word for the specific mouth noise you're describing.

> *interjection, noun*
>   (a sound) used to express disapproval, genuine or
>   mock sympathy, etc.: a click, or sucking sound, made by touching the
>   tongue to the hard palate and rapidly withdrawing it

Perhaps *[raspberries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raspberry)*, as in *to blow raspberries*:

> 2 [short for raspberry tart, rhyming slang for fart] : a sound of
>   contempt made by protruding the tongue between the lips and expelling
>   air forcibly to produce a vibration; broadly : an expression of
>   disapproval or contempt

Comment: Yes, I think 'rasberries' is what they're after.  Or in the cited example:  *a raspberry*

Comment: Okay, tsking  is the closest. Not exactly, but if you make a with pursed lips, it's the closest to what I want. Thanks! @Lynn No, raspberry isn't what I was looking for. Raspberries are rather teasing sounds, what I'm looking for is more of exasperation.

Comment: @asymptotically - It's not limited to teasing sounds, but at any rate I'm glad you found what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 7):

It's known as a [bilabial click](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilabial_click) but that term mightn't be widely understood in the general population, and in linguistics, is a phoneme in certain languages. Note this relevant information from the Wikipedia page:

> The labial clicks are sometimes erroneously described as sounding like
>   a kiss. However, they do not have the pursed lips of a kiss. Instead,
>   the lips are compressed, more like a [p] than a [w], and they sound
>   more like a noisy smack of the lips than a kiss. The exception is the
>   rounded bilabial click of Hadza, which is mimetic of a kiss.

And

> English does not have a labial click (or any click consonant, for that
>   matter) as a phoneme, but a plain bilabial click does occur in
>   mimesis, as a lip-smacking sound children use to imitate a fish.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you mean the noise that is written as 'pfffffft'? it seems to have become popular as a dismissive exclamation in recent years. It is akin to a raspberry, but not as 'wet' since unlike the raspberry, the tongue is not involved in its production. The closest I can think of as far as a name goes is the inelegant `lip-fart`.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pfft

Comment: No, it's not pffffft or lip-fart. It's not a rude sound as such. I'll ask around, and if I find a word better than tsk, I'll write about it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the gesture? If so, it's not a raspberry,"Bronx cheer", but a distantly related, dainty version - a Hoboken kiss, a kiss-off kiss?: [City Fathers - Hoboken, New Jersey, from *The Americans* by Robert Frank, 1958/1959](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JqOi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What's that sound called, the one you make when you purse your lips and make that kissing kind of sound?

It is called a smack.

Smack > a loud kiss

Example: He was left with a bright red lipstick mark after Aunt Mae gave him a big smack on the cheek.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smack
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/smack

Answer (score -1):

It's called kissing your teeth, sucking your teeth, le tchipage / le tchip, and tjoerie in different Caribbean islands.

Answer (score -3):

From OP's supplied context, it seems clear to me the "non-verbal" sound being produced is a [tut](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tut) *interjection: (used as an exclamation of contempt, disdain, impatience, etc.)*. There's an audio link on that dictionary.com page giving both "verbal" and "non-verbal" forms.

There are variations in the precise sound produced, and mechanics of production, but collectively they're all transcribed as "tut" [far more often than "tsk".](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tsk,tut&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

[image]

Comment: Tsk, tsk... ;^) A lot of those _tut_ hits are referring to King Tut, so there's no way to tell for sure if _tut_ is used "far more often" than _tsk_ in this context (at least, not by using that Ngram; [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tut+tut%2Ctsk+tsk&year_start=1935&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3) might be more useful).

Comment: @J.R.: How many is "a lot"? You get the same substantial bias in favour of "tut" with [tsking,tutting](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tsking%2Ctutting&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) or *tsked,tutted*. I think *your* NGram is the misleading one - it suggests *"tsk"* has recently become the more common of the two, which simply isn't true.

Comment: How many? LOL ~ do you want me to count them for you??  When I sifted through a [portion of the results](http://www.google.com/search?q="tut"&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1938,cd_max:1983&lr=lang_en), though, I noticed there were 8 references to the boy king, one to some electical device, and 1 in the context you said. The next page didn't have as many refs to Tut-ankh-amun, but had plenty of other "tut" refs that weren't synonyms for "tsk," either. Your "tsking,tutting" is much better; it still favors "tut", but by nowhere near the margin as the Ngram you originally posted.

Comment: As for which is the more common of the two, that may depend on which side of the ocean you're on.  Go back to my Ngram, and change the corpus to American English.  You'll see that _tsk,tsk_ is favored by an even more pronounced margin.  Change it to British English, though, and _tsk,tsk_ will flatline (which I'm guessing is why you may have been so adamant that my graph was "misleading").  I believe that "tsk" may be nowhere near as foreign-sounding over here as it may be for you over there.

Comment: @J.R.: I'm obviously not denying that *tsk* does in fact occur (it doesn't sound "foreign" to me). All I'm saying is it's less common that *tut*. I think that's still true of recent American usage as well as British, so it seems silly to me that all my answer gets is a single downvote. You can **only** get *tsk* on top with recent US usage of the doubled-up form. Even with just the US corpus, *tutted* and *tutting* consistently outrank *tsked* and *tsking*.

Comment: I never claimed *tsk* was the more common of the two; I only pointed out that your first Ngram was skewed because of other _tut_ references besides _tsk_ vs. _tut_, and therefore inconclusive.

Comment: @J.R.: Hmm. I'm supposing it's not *your* downvote, since it must be clear by now that even though Americans do write *tsk* more often than Brits, we all write *tut* more often than *tsk*. I only wrote this answer because I was pretty sure of that from the beginning. Until you flagged it up, I hadn't realised that bias was less marked in US usage, but it's still true. So far as I'm concerned, these comments and their chart links prove my point, so I'm not going to edit the answer text because it's still substantially correct in its conclusion. *Tsk* is a minority usage.

Comment: The "tsks" before 1930s are generally false positives, and there are a couple of TSK references after the 1930s which are acronyms. I don't think Ngram is the most reliable instrument  here as far as  "noises" or "imitative sounds" are concerned.  And while "...*she tutted under her breath...", is evocative and commonly seen in print, I don't think it's at all common to use *tsked* in reported speech.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Well, you say yourself that you don't think it's at all common to use tsked in reported speech, and the only reason I included the chart at all was to reinforce my own assertion of the same point. So it's not obvious to me why you want to make the point that NGram might not be the most reliable instrument here as far as "noises" or "imitative sounds" are concerned. I'm usually inclined to trust my own personal experience anyway, but that's not considered sufficient for ELU answers like this. So what would you have me do? (Bearing in mind I don't get *paid* for doing this! :)

Comment: I wouldn't use the Ngram chart,  people "say" *tsk* far more often then it is written. Or, I'd limit to  plotting *tsk* and *tut* from the 1940s to the present day and check the results to see if acronyms and Egyptian pharaohs are not skewing the results! :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: You say *people "say" tsk far more often then it is written*, but I have to point out that until I asked [my own question on this subject](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59684/) I really didn't think there were *any* significant number of native speakers who did this. Over the decades I've obviously heard far more people speaking than I've *read*, and usually when I hear someone pronounce something the way it's written rather than how it's normally articulated *in speech*, I tend to assume they just learned it from an inappropriate source medium.