# Word for sound made by tongue and teeth

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

I'm looking for a word that describes the sound made when a person rubs their tongue on the side of their inner teeth. It's like a wet noise and it's supposed to denote a positive gesture rather than negative ([tsking](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/74594/244193))

When I do it, I notice my lips bend upwards.

I wish I could remember a particular scene from a movie/tv show but I can't. However I believe when characters do it, they sometimes also make a gun gesture or point with their fingers.

I've searched quite a bit but haven't found a word that conveys this sound/gesture.

I need it for a scene in a book I'm writing so I can't just explain it, I'll need a word for it if it exists. If not I guess I'll have to change it.

For example in a scene where this gesture will happen it will be:

- Character A: Can you fly this giant space ship?
- Character B: Sure, easy! (then make the sound with his mouth to express it will be easy)

Hope all these ramblings help make it clear what I'm after.

edit: Here's the closest reference I could find, It's the sound Bender makes right around the 29th second mark - http://res.cloudinary.com/yoav-cloud/video/upload/futurama-word_z0jxlm.mp4

Comment: 'Tutting'? This could be misinterpreted for dubstep though.

Comment: thanks though I dont think its quite right. I wasnt familiar with the dance move so good to learn. it did make me think of tooting which is definitely not the direction i was going :)

Comment: Is the sound made just at one side of the mouth? In the situation you describe I would make a 'click' or 'pop' sound by placing the flat of my tongue against the roof of my mouth such that it creates a seal, then(forgive me for this description, I'm sure linguists have words for these actions) pulling down with the centre of the tongue while keeping the edges sealed, so that you create a slight vacuum between the tongue and roof then break the seal at one side where the tongue is closest to the molars.  I would just call that 'clicking my tongue'.

Comment: @Spagirl Maybe this would shed some light on the terminology? https://www.britannica.com/science/mouth-anatomy

Comment: @marcellothearcane Thank you, but having had a quick look at that, I'll stick with layman's terms! :)

Comment: Is there a particular scene in a movie that you're thinking of? Can you find a youtube clip of a person making this sound? It is still very much unclear what sound this is. Is this primarily a general American or British gesture? Or is it used often by some subculture (Southern, surfer duded, cockney, Scots)?

Comment: Ok. Found a reference to share. From a Futurama episode no less. It's not exactly the sound I'm after but its the closest I could find. It's the sound Bender makes right around the 29th second mark - http://res.cloudinary.com/yoav-cloud/video/upload/futurama-word_z0jxlm.mp4

Comment: Based on that clip, I think @Spagirl is right. I'd agree with her in calling the sound a **click**. In the case of guns, those making the sound are immitating the "cocking" of the weapon and indicating their readiness for something. When they are simply pointing, I tend to think of it as occuring with a wink and being like a "sound effect" for the wink itself, but it may still relate to the gun case, I'm not sure.

Comment: "inner teeth"? Are these aliens that have multiple sets of teeth?

Comment: @Barmar i meant the inner/back side of the teeth... But I just might use that multiple set alien teeth idea in a future book... :)

Comment: thanks @Spagirl and steve-lovell - Click does seem close. Yet I wonder if I wrote my scene with something along: 

   --   "Sure. Easy!" Mike answered and clicked his teeth.    --    

would the reader understand what I meant by it. Would they associate the word with the sound/gesture I described? what do you think?

Comment: @poeticGeek clicking your *teeth* would be something different. Perhaps try googling for examples of 'clicked his *tongue*' and see what you think of how others use it. There is more than one way to make a click with your tongue so you may have to say 'clicked his tongue in approval' or something to distinguish from tsking and tutting.

Comment: Thanks @Spagirl, I was hoping to find a more expressive word associated with such a gesture but from my googling I had low expectations. a quick search on "click ones tongue" seems to suggest it being more an expression of a negative feeling rather than what I was imagining. As with the video link I sent and my own requirements, I was looking for something that expresses self-sureness or even mischievousness

Comment: @Spagirl I'd up-vote "clicked his tongue" if you post it as an answer and ping me.

Comment: @poeticGeek and sometimes we hope in vain. As i said, there is more than on sort of tongue click and sometimes you just have to specify which kind you mean, there may be slang terms to cover that sound, but I've not been able to track any down. There are a tonne of google hits for 'he clicked his tongue approvingly/in approval' though so I think that's just how people express it if they have cause to transliterate the sound.

Comment: @poeticgeek It looks as though 'double tongue click' is fairly widely used to convey the sense you are looking for. When I've more time later I will put some of this together as an answer. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+click+of+approval%22&oq=%22a+click+of+approval%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5935j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22double+tongue+click%22&start=10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sound is used as an actual phoneme in many African languages such as Xhosa. In other words, in many languages this sound appears as part of a word. The technical name for a sound of this type is an *unvoiced alveolar lateral click*. In English speaking cultures, this sound is only used non-verbally, where it can have a variety of meanings. For example, English speaking horse-riders will use this sound to encourage their horses to start to move, or speed up. We also sometimes use this when winking as a gesture of camaraderie with the person we're winking to.

For an audio example of a voiceless alveolar lateral click [see here](http://www.phonetics.ucla.edu/course/chapter1/clicks.html).

For instructions on how to make them, see [this video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlocO29uud4).

If *unvoiced alveolar lateral click* is too long, you could of course, refer to it simply as a *click*.

Comment: The OP never really clarified exactly what was being described, so [_click_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_consonant) is probably the closest and covers many possibilities. The Futurama sound was more of a buccal (cheek, one side) click which is not the dental click described in the OP. In informal terms, the OP originally asked for something like the 'tick-tock' sound but the Futurama clip has the 'giddy-up horse' sound.

Comment: @Mitch The giddy-up horse sound (I kinda described it as such in the post) *is* the voiceless alveolar lateral click. The term buccal is an accurate description of the orientation of the closure, in the sense that the closure is made with the side rims of the tongue and the mid/back uppermolars inside the cheek. It often only occurs with the one side of the tongue and the inside of one set of upper molars, but is often equally made with two closures one on either side. If you have a phonetics student trying to make such a click, you simply tell them to do a giddyup noise (not  those words!)

Comment: Love the video, love the letters popping out the speaker's mouth as he teaches viewers the (1) "horseriding click", the (2) "shame click" or "tut, tut" or "ticking clock click";  and the (3) "door knocking click"

Comment: And in the context of OP’s example, I’d say “he clicked his tongue” or “he gave a click” or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I have often thought of this sound as a verbal (or rather mouth-created) "wink" sound, as it is intended to convey a similar sort of sly innuendo or encouragement that a wink of an eye would do.  It's apparently a common enough sentiment that it warrants a subsection on the wikipedia page for "Wink": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wink#The_.22click.22

Urban dictionary calls this sound a [Chlick](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chlick), though I've never heard that term.

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1594&bih=835&site=webhp&q=wink%20click%20mouth&oq=wink%20click%20mouth&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.16234.20002.0.20229.18.18.0.0.0.0.122.1473.17j1.18.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.18.1468...0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i20k1j0i67k1j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1j33i21k1.OXhlsxtxXvc) for "wink click mouth" yields a lot of matching results, none of which seem to have a specific word for the sound.

If I were you I'd somehow use "wink" near "click of the tongue" in your story.  Something like:

> He winked and clicked his tongue in a ridiculously sassy fashion that
>   made her think of Steve Martin doing his Wild And Crazy Guy routine.
>
> "Here's lookin' at you, kid!" he drawled, clearly pleased with
>   himself.
>
> OK, she thought.  Not so much Steve Martin, and more like Chris
>   Kattan.  Doing a Humphrey Bogart impression. Badly.  She closed her eyes to keep from wincing.

Answer (score 0):

The OED describes **tch** as "Representing the dental click used to express vexation."

There is

> "**tch**" (interjection) 1977   Daily Mirror 31 Mar. 24   *Tch! Of all the times to go down wi' flu! We've got a very important darts match tonight!*

The sound is

> a "**tch**" (noun); tch  *n. an utterance of this exclamation.*

the verb is

> "**to tch**" (intransitive) 1907   N. Munro Daft Days ix. 74   *‘You'll find a curious fearless independence in her.’ The twins held up their hands in amazement, ‘tcht-tcht-tchting’ simultaneously.*

The "tch" is used as you say

(i) implying simplicity, or in dismissing something as trivial

(ii) implying annoyance/disapproval

(iii) as Bender uses it, as an encouragement to do something that is a little risky but enjoyable.

I think most native speakers will recognise the distinction from "**tut**" (int.,n., v.) in its pronunciation and "tut" is more associated with (ii) implying annoyance or disapproval.