# Onomatopoeia for click sound made with tongue and mouth?

Tags: word-choice, onomatopoeia

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/397415/347162) question asks what the sound made when clicking one's tongue (sometimes used to express ease or correctness) is *called*.

A slightly different question: is there a specific onomatopoeic expression for this sound (other than the obvious, but more general 'click')?

An example is in Fawlty Towers episode [*The Builders*](https://subslikescript.com/series/Fawlty_Towers-72500/season-1/episode-2-The_Builders):

[image]

> Where is door?

> A-ha

> Door is gone..

> (click sound)

Reference:

- Short video of *The Builders* [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYyEIfKDwC0&t=1m31s).

Comment: Are you thinking of *cluck*? I win, I'm the Big Rooster, the best, Da Man?

Comment: I would call it a "click" and what Basil does is "give a click of approval", or "gives a click of the tongue in approval."

Comment: All speech sounds made (like that one) with ingressive mouth air are called [_click consonants_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_consonant), or just "clicks" for short. There are several dozen variations, many of which are consonants in the so-called "click languages", like ones in the Khoisan family in SW Africa, or several Bantu languages like Zulu which have borrowed some clicks from Khoisan.

Comment: Oh, by the way, this is not onomatopoeia, which means using a word (not just making a sound) that sounds like what it means, so it's only about words like _meow_ or _bang_ that refer to sounds already. That's a very small set of English words.

Comment: I think he's snapping his fingers, not saying anything at that point.

Comment: I think Barmar is correct and I don't understand how the Question could go beyond that, in any direction. Surely even in sub-Saharan African Xhosa tongues, a click of the fingers is very different from any kind of speech… isn't it?