# Is there a WORD For: sound made by mouth to express demeaning annoyance or feigned, mocking disbelief?

Tags: single-word-requests

The sound made by pushing middle tongue against palate, tip of tongue bent downward and pushed up against upper teeth and sucking in air sharply w/ mouth open, chin drops and holds for an instant. A forceful "thch..ahch!"  Often accompanied by eyes rolling upward.  Meant to express demeaning irritation and/or feigned, mocking disbelief at such stupidity, etc.. "Oh brother, there he goes again...! Sarcastic "Do you *believe* he said that?
 I would be happy to borrow from another language if there isn't an English word for it.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59684/why-do-we-write-tsk-for-the-sound-of-disapproval

Comment: I still don't know what this is. Is it what is usually spelled 'tsk tsk'?

Comment: This is like *hum*, *hem* and *hmm*. The word is *tutting*, the way to spell out the sound is *tsk*. It's often associated (in the contexts you describe) with *eye-rolling*.

Comment: I think the 'pfff' sound is appropriate to the above. It is the one made by curling the lip in a sneer and puffing out the bottom lip.

Answer (score 3):

Take your pick from this excellent article on annoying noises people make: [annoying sounds](http://theweek.com/articles/462196/10-annoying-sounds-need-stop-making)

**This one works well for what you are asking**:

**Alveolar, alveopalatal, or postalveolar click**
"Tongue-clucking." Specifically in disapproval. Often done with a slight upward detour of the eyes. Someone else has done something one simply doesn't do, darling, and we're not the sort of person who would actually voice disapproval — how base — but, you know, tsk. In short, an impatient, self-regarding, passive-aggressive condemnation. If you do this, try just… not… doing it.

1. Final rising tone: "Uptalk."
2. Final creaky phonation: "Vocal fry." The latest "OMG this new thing these kids do is going to destroy language!"
3. Fortis voiceless alveopalatal fricative: "Ssssshhhhhhh!"
4. Velar-ingressive linguadental fricative: "Sucking your teeth." Often this is to the side, not right in the middle.
5. Pulmonic-ingressive breathy-voiced rising-tone neutral vowel: "Gasp."
6. Fortis long final consonant with epenthetic neutral vowel: "Don't-tuh do this-suh." [My personal favorite]
7. Pulmonic ingressive voiceless alveolar glide and mid-central vowel, with optional unreleased final bilabial stop: Inhaled "Yeah" or "Yep."
8. Sustained mid-central vowel and/or bilabial nasal: "Uhhh… uhmmmm… mmmmm…"
9. Alveolar, alveopalatal, or postalveolar click: "Tongue-clucking." Specifically in disapproval. Often done with a slight upward detour of the eyes.
10. Loud long low back vowel with advanced tongue root and full oral opening: "Moose-call yawns."

The author, James Harbeck deserves a huge PRIZE for his priceless article!

There are 10 of them and so well described.

CLICK ON THE VIDEO in the LINK :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the phrase "sucking your teeth." I didn't know what that term meant until I made that sound at a friend who said, "Don't suck your teeth at me!" Interesting article about it: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/11651574/French-schools-ban-teeth-sucking.html

Answer (score 1):

Tsk tsk is the right answer. Although I guess there is another sound similar to it but it is made just once (and a bit as louder). One may call it just tsk. I don't know if in the literary community it has been universally accepted as a fact.

It involves separating both the lips also besides tongue and teeth. But quickly.

The combination of the quick separation - 1. of both lips 2. teeth and tongue from upper region of mouth (palate I guess) - make one sound that depicts frustration or disapproval.

I personally find it offensive when someone makes it even for genuine reasons. I wish no one did that.

Disclaimer. I do it sometimes myself. I try not do it.

Comment: Or "tut tut", Of course once people have read "tut" they tend to pronounce it as a word!  The same is true for many such sounds, for example "Ugh!" - a sound of revulsion made with the back of the tongue, is often pronounced "Ug" when read.  Until we start using the IPA to print English, this sort  of thing is inevitable. The standard alphabet just can't cope. Note:  "tsk tsk" could be read as "tusk tusk" or similar. This is one of the banes of an author's life.