# Specific usage of "more"

Tags: word-usage, british-english, literary-english

I was reading E.M. Forster's *A Room With A View* and came across this dialogue:

> “Up to now I have never kissed you.” She was as scarlet as if he had put the thing most indelicately. “No—more you have,” she stammered.

I had never encountered this usage of "more" before and have not been able to find it in the dictionaries. In fact, I am not exactly sure what the female character (Lucy) means here: indeed you haven't? You never have? I would appreciate examples with the same usage if possible.

Comment: Undecipherable except that she's embarassed.

Comment: I've been trying to track down the original separator (punctuation) between _No_ and _more_. I think it shows the stammer; I'd use an ellipsis. // I think the 'No more' here is merely [an attempt at] a total agreement, 'That's no more than the honest truth' ... an archaism. 'You haven't, either!' (_either_ ...  for that matter – used for emphasis; [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/either))

Comment: Yes, it does make more sense when read as "No more", although still not completely (to my mind) - it would fit well if Cecil (her interlocutor) had said "You have never kissed me" and she replied with "No more have you", meaning, you didn't try to kiss me either, here's the pot calling the kettle black. At any rate, I'm glad to see that the sense is not immediately clear to others either.

Comment: It's an unusual stylised / poetic / literary usage, where ***no more*** is effectively an "intensifier". Lucy's reply is equivalent to ***Indeed** you have not [kissed me]*. Perhaps we should simply interpret the unusual phrasing as further evidence that Lucy is embarrassed / confused by this turn of the conversation, so she "stumbles over her words" a bit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Nope, you've done more."

Comment: @tchrist: I'll shut up then (after noting that ***nope*** is used [*to signal the **end** of the word, answer, utterance, and discussion*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59670/2637))

Comment: If the screenplay for the 1985 movie rendition of this book is anything to go by, previous commenters are correct in saying that Lucy is agreeing with Cecil. In the screenplay, Lucy's response is *"(stammering in embarrassment not at the request but at his clumsiness) No -- you haven't."*

Source: https://www.scribd.com/document/164881089/A-Room-With-A-View# -- this link may be pay-walled for some, but the scene occurs on pages 62-63.

Comment: It is ambiguous , maybe the author wanted to show that she was dumbstruck , maybe the author wanted to be ambiguous , unless there was some clarification in later writings or interviews ! [ Meaning 1 : “No ! You have done more!” ] [ Meaning 2 : “You have done nothing more !” ] [ Meaning 3 : "Yes , you have not !" ] [ Meaning 4 : Speaker is blabbering ]

Comment: I think I've heard "more" used similarly to "in fact", as in "no -- in fact, you have [kissed me]"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the next line in [the original on Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2641/2641-h/2641-h.htm) or [Google Books:](https://books.google.com/books?id=I_9KAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=a+room+with+a+view&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv-feGoIb-AhWdjokEHX0nDgoQ6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=kissed&f=false)

> “Then I ask you—may I now?”

I suspect the implication is that he interjected mid-stammer; "more you have" is most likely the incomplete start of a new sentence.

Comment: The original? Probably [[Project Gutenberg Practices ... Newby](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/60600/60600-h/60600-h.htm): 'In practice, all eBooks published by Project Gutenberg still have errors, even if they are far better than 99% accurate.']

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Added a citation to Google Books, which has the same line.